# random load images not from within same directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want an image to load randomly every time the page reloads. However the code to be used cannot just pick a photo out of a certain directory, but it needs to each time randomly choose one of the preset paths to a different photo in a different directories.

Preset path are these:

https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097622657/eddy-hilhorst-fotel-photography-courses-tours.jpg

https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097622663/hiromi-fujii-fotel-photography-courses-tours.jpg

https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097622666/jungsoon-suh-fotel-photography-courses-tours.jpg

Some code here below. The photo already visible in the code below should be taken out. Have it there so something is visible now.

```css
#myContainer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 8px;
}

#myPhoto {
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -8px
}
```

```html
<div id="myContainer">
    <img id="myPhoto" src=" https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097160429/eddyhilhorst-fotelphotographycoursesandtours-no-lo.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Teemu, been searching, but can only find code that uses images that reside within the same directory.

Comment: `var images = ["https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097622657/eddy-hilhorst-fotel-photography-courses-tours.jpg","https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097622663/hiromi-fujii-fotel-photography-courses-tours.jpg","https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097622666/jungsoon-suh-fotel-photography-courses-tours.jpg"];` and have `document.getElementById("myPhoto").src=images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];`

Comment: Those examples use an array to store relative paths to images, right? What prevents you to store absolute addresses instead?

Comment: I upload the images in a webshop backoffice that generates the URL's were the images are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var images = [
 'https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097622657/eddy-hilhorst-fotel-photography-courses-tours.jpg',
        'https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097622663/hiromi-fujii-fotel-photography-courses-tours.jpg',
        'https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097622666/jungsoon-suh-fotel-photography-courses-tours.jpg'
];



var rand = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

document.querySelector('#myPhoto').src = rand;
```

```html
<div id="myContainer">
    <img id="myPhoto" src=" https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097160429/eddyhilhorst-fotelphotographycoursesandtours-no-lo.jpg" />
</div>
```

Now it is possible that you get the same image shown a few times in a row as this is part of random. It is less a problem with lots more images though.

Comment: @Eddy of course it does :) you are welcome, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You could pick a random integer between 0 and the length of your pictures array in every load using `Math.random()` Then change the source `src` by the picked picture with random index generated:

```
var pictures_array = [];
var min=0;
var max=pictures_array.length;
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;

$('#myPhoto').attr('src', pictures_array[random]);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var pictures_array = [
  'https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097622657/eddy-hilhorst-fotel-photography-courses-tours.jpg',
  'https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097622663/hiromi-fujii-fotel-photography-courses-tours.jpg',
  'https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/054833/files/097622666/jungsoon-suh-fotel-photography-courses-tours.jpg'
];

var min=0;
var max=pictures_array.length;
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;

$('#myPhoto').attr('src', pictures_array[random]);
```

```css
#myContainer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 8px;
}

#myPhoto {
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -8px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myContainer">
    <img id="myPhoto" src="" />
</div>
```